# CSS question - transparent underlined textbox - howto?

Tags: css, textbox, styles

Good Morning,

Quick CSS question. Does anyone know any quick css to make an underlined transparent textbox? I basically want the textbox to be invisible except for the bottom border. I need it to function normally. Do I just remove left, right, and top borders and set it's background to transparent or something? Any examples of how to properly accomplish this? This app is for IE7 if that's relevant. Any help is always appreciated.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should do it:

```
input.myBox
{
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Tested in IE8 (IE7 compatability mode)

Answer (score 6):

Just a suggestion... since people are **not** going to be used to this, you may want to add a hover pseudoclass as well to change the color slightly when the user mouses over the field, as an extra visual "hint" of what's going on.

Example:

```
input.myBox:hover
{
   border-color: #000066;
   background-color: #FFFFF7;
}
```

Comment: Good note. Check the rule of least astonishment in wikipedia for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your left, right and top borders values to be **none**

```css
#textarea {
    font-size: large;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding:10px,20px;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: vertical;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border-top:none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
```

```html
 <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your message here.."></textarea>
```